# convert hive date query to oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

How can I convert the below listed hive queries to oracle sql? I copied the queries that I converted in "EDIT" section. Are they correct?

**Query 1**

```
date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180515','yyyyMMdd')),1)
```

**Query 2**

```
concat(substring(min(cretn_dt),1,10),"T",substring(from_unixtime(
    unix_timestamp(min(cretn_dt),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),12,20),"Z")
```

**EDIT:**

Converted query 1 to below :

```
 select to_date('20180515','yyyyMMdd') - 1 from dual;
```

Converted query 2 to below :

```
 select to_char(min(cretn_dt),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Comment: Do they produce the answers you expect?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , I am not sure what the original hive query produces as I just have access to the code and don't have the necessary setup to run. I googled the details of hive functions and tried to convert them into oracle equivalent.